# shmget shmat is not working properly

Tags: c++, linux, memory, shared-memory

```
    class test_class
    {
       public:
       std::string str;
       int ival;
    };

    int main()
    {
        int shmkey = 3450;
        int shmid;

        if((shmid = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(test_class*), IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
        {
            perror("shmget");
            exit(1);
        }

        test_class **test_obj;
        if((test_obj = (test_class**) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (test_class**) -1)
        {
            perror("shmat");
            exit(1);
        }

        test_class* new_obj = new test_class();
        *test_obj = new_obj;

        (*test_obj)->str = "parent process string";
        (*test_obj)->ival = 9;

        pid_t pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0)
        {
            int shmkey = 3450;
            int shmid;

            if((shmid = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(test_class*), 0666)) < 0)
            {
                perror("shmget");
               exit(1);
            }

            test_class **test_obj;
            if((test_obj = (test_class**) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (test_class**) -1)
            {
                perror("shmat");
                exit(1);
            }

            (*test_obj)->str = "child process string";
            (*test_obj)->ival = 10;

            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        sleep(3);
        std::cout << (*test_obj)->str << std::endl;
        std::cout << (*test_obj)->ival << std::endl;

        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0);

        return 0;
    }


This code output is :-
child process string
9
```

In this program i am updating the shared memory object (in heap memory) in child process and printing updated values in parent. As we see from output it is correctly updating string but not int. As it is in heap memory it should not update. How string is updating here ?

Any help on this ?

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several issues:

1) parent process doesn't wait for child process to finish modification of the object, so it's unpredictable what it would output. Put `wait(NULL)` into the parent process before outputting the values;

2) child process changes an `std::string`, and in fact it changes some pointers inside the `string` object, but the child and the parent have different heaps and different address spaces, so this is very dangerous. You should store array of `char` in the shared memory instead;

3) there is no need to perform `shmget`&`shmat` in child process as the shared memory is already obtained in parent process and duplicated in `fork`;

4) you should specify fields of the `test_class` as `volatile` so that compiler wouldn't optimize away reading their values.

Comment: 5) You are storing a pointer to non-shared memory in the shared memory block with `*test_obj = new test_class();`. This will work in your example program, but only because the entire address space is effectively copied in to the child process at `fork()`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've overlooked that - I thought he stored an object and not a pointer there.

Comment: If I was storing the object, I don't think this problem occurred. Anyway, My point is here, how string is updated in child process as it is also in heap memory ?

Comment: The string is NOT updated in parent process. I have just compiled your code, and it printed "parent string" as it should be. Maybe you are not showing us the real code?

Comment: Thanks Inspired! You are right it is not real code. I got it, it was happening because of my one mistake in real code. String is also not updated.